# how to add incremental numbers in pyspark map

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, rdd

I have this code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

ts = time.time()
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

claims_data = data.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
claim_id = claims_data.map(lambda x: (
    x[9],
    'Claim_id',
    '0',
    'Claim_id',
    'Claim',
    1,
))

BeginDOS = claims_data.map(lambda x: (
    x[13],
    'BeginDOS',
    '0',
    'BeginDOS',
    'Claim',
    1,
))
```

I'm trying to trnasform data from an existing RDD, and here's what I'm trying to do:

This code example extracts a single column.  claim_id is x[9] and BeginDOS is x[13] of the currently loaded RDD called `data`.  Using maps, I am creating new RDDs using static data for each column.  i am going to add more maps as time goes.

My question is the last field.  In these cases both are hardset to the numerical value 1.

What I need is to instantiate a variable counter, and pre load that variable with a number.  I want to use that number in `claim_id` and `BeginDOS`, but increment it each time.  for each record in `claim_id`, it increments, as does `BeginDOS`

how do I do this?

Thanks

UPDATE #1.  Example of source data as requested:

```
1,001,885,2HZL911L0,00,99,,L91279331,001,71,59404,03,MED,2014-05-28,2014-05-28,72885,7840,8460,8470,8471,8472,,920,920,0,0,2014-07-09,C,261435747,U,U6FIL,1,,2014-05-28,2014-05-28,12,0,R0129,845,845,0,U6FIL
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you include a sample of `data` ?

Comment: I put in some.  Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

By your example I'm assuming you want your indices to be 1-based (not-0).

If so this should get you what you want (can use this template for both variables):

```
claim_ids = map(lambda x: (
    x[1][13],
    'BeginDOS',
    '0',
    'BeginDOS',
    'Claim',
    x[0]+1,
),enumerate(claims_data))

[('2014-05-28', 'BeginDOS', '0', 'BeginDOS', 'Claim', 1),
 ('2014-05-28', 'BeginDOS', '0', 'BeginDOS', 'Claim', 2)]

# the x used in the lambda is a tuple with (index#,value)
```

Comment: Thanks, bu tit's giving me the `TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable` error.

Comment: gotcha. I didn't see that claims_data is also an RDD, my bad